# CSV flies lost when transferred

Tags: data-loss, csv

I changed my OS from Linux to Windows 10 a week back. I saved a few CSV files and some code. After clearing the hard drive and making the switch, I realized that the CSV files were saved in this format:

```
.~locked.filename.csv#
```

I converted it to CSV by changing its name, but on my CSV reader, I just get a blank screen. This has never happened before. How can I get back my lost data?

Answer (score 1):

Im sorry to say it, but you possibly lost your `csv` files, because most of the programs make `lock` files, which prevent opening file in different instance to exclude possibility of data corruption due to simultaneous, for example, save operations. Your `.~locked.filename.csv#` is just a flag.

But i suggest you not get upset too soon. Shut down your PC (to prevent overwriting disk blocks, which contain your "deleted" `csv` files) and read [this](https://itsfoss.com/recover-deleted-files-linux/) article